# Vector movement with respect to rotation

Tags: vector, rotation, trigonometry

Say I have a vector (x,y) and it is aligned to the origin by a rotation (say, pointing 30 degrees up).

If I want to move that vector one unit with respect to the direction (so, one unit forward facing 30 degrees up), how would I go about doing so?

I'm working on putting a simple third-person game together and I would like to be able to rotate the character and move it forward regardless of rotation, and I'm kind of lost as to how to do this.

EDIT:

After this question was answered, I went ahead and figured out how to get a backwards, left, and right movement, so I figured I'd stick this in here for reference if anyone needs help.

Given Gunther2's code, 
To get a backwards motion, simply subtract the displacement from the current position:

```
position -= displacement;
```

To get a left motion, change the displacement variables to

```
displacement.x = (float)Math.Sin(angle + PI/2); 
displacement.y = (float)Math.Cos(angle + PI/2);
```

Replace PI/2 with 90 if Sin/Cos accepts degrees instead of radians.

Then subtract displacement:

```
position -= displacement;
```

To get a right motion, simply follow the same steps but add the new displacement:

```
position += displacement;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you would need a vector representing the angle:

```
Vector2 displacement;
displacement.x = (float)Math.Sin(angle);
displacement.y = (float)Math.Cos(angle);
```

Then, since the length of this vector (x,y) will always be 1, you multiply it by how far you're traveling.  If you want to travel a distance of 1, then X and Y are already the size they need to be.

```
displacement *= speed;  // Assuming your Vector2 *= operator supports a scalar
```

Add the displacement to the current position:

```
position += displacement;
```

Comment: Perfect! I was actually using a Vector3 but I adapted the code to suit it -- I was EXTREMELY confused for a while there because the Mathf.Sin and Cos functions in Unity (which is what I'm using) take a radian value and not a degree one (which is kinda what they supply for rotation). But after I got over that hurdle, it works great! Thank you so much!

Comment: These are my favorite types of questions. Glad I could help :]